# Table view cell scaling animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

Hi I am new to IOS devlopment.I need my table view cell to animate like scaling animation(i. e.whenever I scroll up the cell need to scale out based on scrolling position and whenever I scroll down the cell should scale in based on scrolling position).I tried to find but I can't able to trigger out the actual solution.Can anyone help me out regarding this.Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please describe the problem or what you try to do better in the topic, so people will understand you better and hopefully answer your question

Comment: I need the same table view cell animation as shown in that application...thats my post regarding.

Comment: I'd advise you to edit your question and show EXACTLY what you look for so it'd be easy for others to see what you look for. Having to go and download another app is too much of a hassle. I'd suggest you will upload a video/gif of the animation.

Comment: I need icarousel rotary type animation for UiTableview cell animation.Can anyone help me regarding this please.....

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1,1)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1,1,1)
        })
    }
```

Dont forgot to add `delegate` and `datasource` to your `tableview`.for more http://developers-club.com/posts/234853/